# Linking a Background Image

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, background

I am trying to link my background image using the tutorial over at http://xavisys.com/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/#comment-28009 but it's just not working for me.

I think I have the css right, but when I insert the html to make the link, it sets my WHOLE site as one giant link. Is there a way to make the link layer behind my content so it is only clickable on the sides of the container?

I've tried using this css:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/bg.png'); 
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }

body #background-link {
position: absolute;
height:11000px;
text-indent:-9999px;
width:1440px;
top: 0; left: 0;
border: 0;
float: left;
}
```

and this html:

```
<a href="http://url.com" title="Title" id="background-link">the link</a>
```

Comment: FYI - this was not intended to make the entire background of the site a link, it was intended for a single image background within a site. It should work if you use the code below though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the z-index of the container of the site so that it is higher than the anchor link. The simple way to do this -

Add this CSS:

```
#wrapper{position:relative;z-index:10;}
#background-link{z-index:1}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://url.com" title="Title" id="background-link">the link</a>
<div id="wrapper">
    all of your site code goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `position:absolute` makes you're link stay in front. You can probably try `z-index`, but is easier to tell if i can see you're entire code? Or page-link?

Comment: `
body {
   background-image: url('images/bg.png'); 
 background-position: center top;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

body #background-link {
 position: absolute;
 height:11000px;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 width:1440px;
 top: 0; left: 0;
 border: 0;
 float: left;
}

h1 {font-size: 18pt;}
h2 {font-size: 14pt;}
h3 {font-size: 10pt;}
h4 {font-size: 9pt;}

/* container */


#container {
 width:971px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 overflow:hidden;
 background: url(images/notebookbg.gif) top center repeat-y scroll;
}`

Comment: Can you also tell me exactly what you want? Why do you need this link behind it all? Try set z-index:-1 on the link, and position:absolute. Is that what you want?

Comment: So, now the clickable background image is below, not behind the content. If you check out my site and scroll down past the content, you will get to the clickable part.

Comment: Yes i can see. That is because you need to remove z-index on body, add z-index:2 and position:relative on container, set z-index:1 on the link.

Comment: Np, glad i could help :) But i guess you need to think about the customer, do they wan't the entire background to redirect them to another page/site?

Comment: actually yes! The people that visit my site are looking for prom dresses and if they click on the ads that sit on my background image, they will be redirected to one of the best prom dress sites on the web. :)